# Digital Data Layer

Tags: magento-2.1, layer

I need to implement digital data layer for marketing. I already tried this tool https://github.com/digitalDataLayer/magento2 but this produce error. So I am looking for help.

Comment: I found this useful: https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_GoogleTagManager2
Still checking this and better alternative.